# C file extension Check

Tags: c

My question seems simple but I get thrown in various directions on google, but my question is In c how would one check if a command line inputted file has a specific extension like ".fs" and simply remove it from said file?

Comment: It will check 3 last characters of the string and replace with `\0`

Comment: Are you literally asking how to remove the last 3 characters from a string?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
int main(int c, char *v[])
{
   char *ext;
   if (c > 1)
   {
       printf("before %s\n", v[1]);
       /* check the first arg */
       ext = v[1] + strlen(v[1]) - strlen(".fs");
       if (strcmp(ext, ".fs") == 0)
         *ext = '\0';
       printf("after %s\n", v[1]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how would one check if a command line inputted file has a specific
>   extension like ".fs" and simply remove it from said file?

Suppose you have the name stored like this:

```
char name[32];
strcpy(name, "test.fs");
```

You find the extension like this:

```
char * extension = NULL;
for (int i = 0; name[i]; i++) {
    if (name[i] == '.') {
        extension = &name[i];
    }
}
printf("ext: %s\n", extension);
```

And remove it like this:

```
if (extension && !strcmp(".fs", extension)) {
    extension[0] = '\0';
}
printf("full: %s\n", name);
```